# When would a creature fail to cast a spell from a scroll?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

The Variant Rule "Scroll Mishaps" in the DMG (page 140) has a header with the following text:

> A creature who tries and fails to cast a spell from a spell scroll
>   must make a DC 10 Intelligence saving throw. If the saving
>   throw fails, roll on the Scroll Mishap table.

Under what circumstances can a creature try to cast a spell from a spell scroll and fail?

The rules for using a Scroll (page 139) don't require any checks and don't involve any failure chance. Or is part of this rule that the DM should set rules for how one casts from a scroll?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### The failure is possible if trying to cast a spell with a level higher than you can cast from a Spell Scroll.

**Spell Scroll, DMG pg.200:**

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list but of a higher level than you can normally cast, you must make an ability check using your Spellcasting ability to determine whether you cast it successfully. The DC equals 10 + the spell’s level. On a failed check, the spell disappears from the scroll with no other effect.

The general rule for scrolls in the DMG pg 139 is *"Any creature that can understand a written language can read the arcane script on a scroll and attempt to activate it."*, however, the specific rule for Spell Scrolls says "If the spell is on your class's list you can use an action to read the scroll [...] Otherwise, the scroll is unintelligible".

Basically, if you can read you can use a scroll (ex: Scroll of Protection, DMG 199), but only if the spell is on your list you can use an Spell Scroll (DMG 200).

A even more specific exception to this rule is the Use Magic Device feature of the 13th-level Thief (Roguish Archetype): *"You ignore all class, race, and level requirements on the use of magic items."* Jeremy Crawford [tweeted](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2014/12/05/use-magic-device-and-scroll/) *"The intent is that Use Magic Device does allow a rogue to try to use a scroll."* Since everyone can use a normal scroll, he meant the use of a Spell Scroll.

Comment: Interesting. That description contradicts what it says in the Scroll section under the main header. (pg 139)

Comment: @Erik Like everything in D&D, specific beats general.

Comment: @Erik it doesn't contradict. It's an additional option for what to do when you fail the spell scroll check.

Comment: @Erik I think your confusion is that *Spell Scrolls* are scrolls, but not all scrolls are *spell scrolls*. There are general rules for scrolls, and then spell scrolls are a particular type of scroll which have their own rules for who can use them, as per the general rule about trying to use scrolls: "Unless a scroll's description says otherwise..."